# Normalization Exercise Resources

Tags: normalization

I want to sharpen my database normalization skills.  Where can I find good quality beginner-to-advanced level exercises (with solutions) on the web ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following are the resources which I'm using to brush-up my database skills and to teach newbies...

1. [Animated DataBase Courseware](http://adbc.kennesaw.edu/)

   - From Database Design to Advanced Concepts
2. [wofford-ecs.org](http://wofford-ecs.org/DataAndVisualization/DatabaseDevelopment/material.htm)

   - Database Design - Normalization
3. [db4u](http://db4u.wikidot.com/normexercises)

   - Normalization exercises
4. http://www.sql-ex.ru/

   - Tons of sql exercises
5. http://www.tekstenuitleg.net/en/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/intro.html

   - Database Design Tutorial

Comment: The No.1 looks especially great

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short introduction.

http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/585228-database-normalization-table-structures